# Relations between numbers taken three at a time

Tags: mathematics

Let's have the following numbers.

$(5i+\frac{1}{2})$, $(2i+3)$, $(\frac{-101}{8})$, $(7i+4)$, $(5i+1)$, $\frac{(40i-97)}{8}$.

How are these numbers related when taken three at a time?
Operations allowed + - x  ÷ ^

HINT: The three numbers, when chosen correctly, will solve this equation: $x^3=a^2-b^2$

There is only one solution.

Comment: This looks to be another "guess what I'm thinking" problem. Three are probably infinitely many relationships one could draw.

Comment: When the numbers are chosen correctly, three at a time, (no more than three numbers) there is only one answer.

Comment: That's not a hint, it's the problem statement. Without telling us what equation to solve, *this isn't a puzzle*. It's a guessing game.

Comment: @ bobble. Choose the three numbers with denominators then you can answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you were thinking but here is one possibility

> $(2i+3)+(5i+1)+\frac{(40i-97)}{8} = \left(5i+\frac{1}{2}\right) + (7i+4) + \left(\frac{-101}{8}\right)$

Comment: Your answer uses six numbers not three at a time.

Comment: Three on the left, three on the right.

Comment: If you meant e.g. "what relation holds between my first three numbers and also between the other three numbers?" then you should have said that. But it would still have been a "guess what I'm thinking" puzzle.

Comment: As stated in the question, take three number and using these three numbers, find a solution.